# activator dist failing when using Scala 2.12.0

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe-activator

I updated the scala version in my build.sbt file to 2.12.0 from 2.11.8.

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.0"
```

But now **activator dist** is failing with the following errors. Please advise:

```
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.12;1.1.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.12;1.1.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/ubuntu/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/twirl-api_2.12/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/twirl-api_2.12/1.1.1/twirl-api_2.12-1.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   /home/ubuntu/activator/repository/com.typesafe.play/twirl-api_2.12/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/twirl-api_2.12/1.1.1/twirl-api_2.12-1.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/twirl-api_2.12/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your dependencies (`twirl-api`) has not been released for Scala 2.12. You need to remove this dependency, get it published on 2.12, or else stay on Scala 2.11.